# Environment specific dataprovider

Tags: testng, test-data, test-environments, testng-dataprovider

My requirement : Different data for different environments.

I believe this is a common requirement, and I am looking for suggestions on best practices to go about doing this. Is there a way dataprovider in testNg can be made to supply data based on the environment? Dataseeding is not an option at the moment, so making sure loading same data in different environments is not an option. 
The option that I can think of, is to have as many excels as there are environments. But that would mean breaking this down further to have excels specific to a testcase. And writing extra code to 
pick the right excel based on an environment variable (that can be passed from command line or as a JVM param), and the test case.I feel this is an overkill, and there should be a simpler way of doing this. Looking forward to some suggestions. Thank you.